# Haskell : unexpected ´;' possibly due to bad layout

Tags: haskell, syntax-error

I have to write an easy program telling me, how many solutions has a quadratic equation. I wrote:

```
howManySolutions :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Int

howManySolutions a b c = if (b^2-(4*a*c)) > 0 then 2 else 
                         if (b^2-(4*a*c)) == 0 then 1
                         else -1
```

but in WinHugs I get syntax error:

```
  unexpected ´;' possibly due to bad layout
```

I can open my program in GHCi, but it doesn't let me use negative numbers... What am i doing wrong?

Comment: This works fine for me (using GHC). I'm confused about why you return `-1` in the base `b^2-4*a*c < 0` though - surely you should return `0`?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by GHCi not letting you use negative numbers? Which error did you get?

Comment: -1 was just an idea of our teacher, I guess I have to convert the result -1 to Int yet... But is it the reason for my error?
After opening my program with GHCi I gave numbers 2 -2 3 and got an error: No instance for (Num (Float -> Float -> Float -> Int)) arising from an use of '-' "

Comment: That is because your minus is parsed as subtraction rather than negation. See Alex Appetiti's answer for details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure about the winhugs problem, but I can help you with the ghci one.

First of all, a bit of indentation:

```
howManySolutions a b c = if (b^2-(4*a*c)) > 0
                         then 2
                         else 
                           if (b^2-(4*a*c)) == 0
                           then 1
                           else -1
```

Now, if you try entering `howManySolutions -1 2 3` into ghci, you get `No instance for (Num (Float -> Float -> Float -> Int)) arising from a use of '-'`. Basically it's interpreting '-' as a function to apply to 1 2 and 3 instead of just applying it to the '1'.

All you need to do is enter it as `howManySolutions (-1) 2 3`.

Now, if I can give you a tip, the way that patterns like this are usually handled are like so:

```
howManySolutions a b c
  | delta > 0 = 2
  | delta == 0 = 1
  | otherwise = -1
  where delta = b^2-4*a*c
```

the '|' symbols (guards) act as different 'ifs', and the 'where' clause at the bottom let you define delta once to reuse multiple times in the guards. It's prettier :D

Comment: Yup, that's likely it re: negative numbers.

Comment: Ok, now it works with (-1)! Thank you very much for fast help, you spared me much time and tears ;)

Answer (score 1):

just use the right indentation

```
howManySolutions a b c = if (b^2-(4*a*c)) > 0 
                            then 2 
                            else if (b^2-(4*a*c)) == 0 
                                    then 1
                                    else (-1)
```

a more idiomatic solution would be

```
sol a b c | d >  0 = 2          
          | d <  0 = 0          
          | d == 0 = 1          
          where d = b^2-(4*a*c)
```

Comment: While this is more readable, the original snippet is syntactically valid. (I had no problems loading it from GHCi.)

Comment: I know! It opens with GHCi but not with winHugs, I wish I knew why.

Comment: GHC has some extensions that allow it to be more relaxed about indenting.  http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/release-7-2-1.html

Comment: @AaronMcDaid There are no layout heralds in this code, so I don't see how indentation can matter, with or without GHC's extensions. I suspect we're not getting the full story somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Using `-1` is a bad idea for Haskell.  You could use `Maybe a` instead, like:

```
howManySolutions :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Maybe Int
howManySolutions a b c = let delta = b^2-(4*a*c) in
             if delta > 0 
             then Just 2 
             else if delta == 0 
                  then Just 1
                  else Nothing
```

Comment: It was the wish of my teacher to use -1. i don't like that idea tho.